Сдвинуть точку А к точке Б на заданую дистанцию
Даны 2 точки Vector3 А и Б, которые представляют собой Vector3
Необходимо А сдвинуть в сторону Б на заданую дистанцию.
В начале думал, что нужно просто прибавить дистанцию к координатам вектора А, но мне почему-то кажется, что я получу не совсем то, что нужно.

Что значит "сдвинуть вектор"?

Чуть подправил. Там точки, которые представляют собой Vector3

Нормализуем вектор от A к B (сделаем единичной длины) и прибавим к A вектор длины Dist и с нужным направлением
AB = B - A
uAB = AB / AB.Magnitude
C = A + Dist * uAB

В коде:
    Vector3D A = new Vector3D(0, 0, 0);
    Vector3D B = new Vector3D(3, 4, 5);
    Vector3D AB = B - A;
    AB.Normalize();
    double Dist = 2.0;
    Vector3D C = A + Dist*AB;
    Console.WriteLine(C.X +" " + C.Y + " " + C.Z);
    Console.ReadKey();

>>0.848528137423857 1.13137084989848 1.41421356237309    


А можно пожалуйста снизу подписать шаровую реализацию от и до?

а зачем Vector3D AB = new Vector3D(); если на следующей строчке ты тут же заменяешь все AB = B - A;? И с C - то же самое

@Grundy Языков я не знаю, Петька...(© Чапаев) У меня не получилось объявление с инициализацией разностью. Если шарп это позволяет - конечно, лучше сделать сразу. Я вижу только один конструктор с тремя компонентами.

@MBo, а что мешало просто  Vector3D AB = B - A сделать? Выглядит вполне логично ведь

@Grundy Скудоумие мешало ;) Посмотрел на пример кода с Vector3D у Microsoft - там все сначала создавались, потом использовались, и по аналогии написал. Спасибо за подсказку.

@MBo, Действительно, что-то они там перемудрили :-D

@MBo вопросик небольшой. А как ограничить сдвиг? Чтобы если я сдвигаю А к Б на расстоение 500 и если при сдвиге я уйду за точку Б, то взять Б ?

А... Все. Просто добавил в алгоритм предварительную проверку дистанции от одной точки до другой. Если дистанции меньше, чем расстояние на которое ссдвигаемся, то беру просто конечную точку.

Шаг первый: найти направление из точки А в точку Б. Таких векторов бесконечно много, различающихся длиной. Один из них это разность между векторами Б и А, то есть Б-А (в ответе MBo это строка AB = B - A)
Шаг второй: придать этому вектору заданную длину/дистанцию. Нужно этот вектор разделить на его собственную длину/модуль, и умножить на заданную длину. Иногда этот шаг разбивают на два: 1) разделить на собственную длину, то есть получить единичный вектор направления (AB.Normalize()) 2) умножить на заданную длину, то есть отмасштабировать (Dist*AB).
Шаг третий: Сделать так, чтоб этот вектор выходил из точки А, а не из начал координат, то есть прибавить к А (C = A + Dist*AB)
